# Angularjs: ng-show not showing after set to true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="callMe()"
    ng-show="isVisible">Call</button>
```

In my controller.js I tried to:

```
$scope.isVisible = false;
myService.callMe().success(function (response) {
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    alert("enabled");
}
```

But button "Call" is not showing (alert was shown). What went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you click your button which is not visible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed the service call inside the function,

```
$scope.callMe = function(){
myService.callMe().success(function (response) {
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    alert("enabled");
}
}
```

I am not sure why you are using a service here, you can do without service as,

```
$scope.callMe = function(){    
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    alert("enabled");     
}
```

**[`WORKING DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/YkH0wz5BiC6DrbfFsYZg?p=preview)**

Comment: I actually have embedded it inside a function. But has no effect.

Comment: Can we modify $scope.isVisible even if callMe() wasn't called?

Comment: that is vey strange, can you produce a plunker

Comment: oh wait, you do not need a service here. check the modified answer

Comment: it actually runs when inside a function. But what if the callMe() wasnt called and I just want to show the button (set to true) from other method. Is it possible?

Comment: @Zerosero no that is not possible, because you are waiting for it to return the success . you can place it outside

Comment: you mean set it to true outside the callMe() function? that's what I actually did

Comment: issue is that you had some typo on funciton names here is the working demo https://plnkr.co/edit/YkH0wz5BiC6DrbfFsYZg?p=preview

Comment: yea, I should really be keen on simple details too. Thanks